# Generating Symbol file (.sym) on Mips

Tags: gdb, mips, debug-symbols

Is there any command / utlity to generate symbol file (.sym) from executable for MIPS platform?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use "nm" command line utility? Is that good enough?
Try to:
nm -C

Comment: I was basically looking for STACK CFI info from executable.. So nm wont help.. Anyways thanks :)